# I Want to Generate Search Engine Friendly urls

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I Want to Generate Search Engine Friendly urls for eg:- say I have a link below like

http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php?id=AP112&title=ADVANCED%20OFFICE%20AUTOMATION%20SYSTEM%20USING%20GSM%20AND%20MICROCONTROLLER

I Just want it to be

http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php/AP112/ADVANCED%20OFFICE%20AUTOMATION%20SYSTEM%20USING%20GSM%20AND%20MICROCONTROLLER

I tried with rewrite in .htaccess but didnt succeeded even Im not getting how to GET parameters once link is converted to seo friendly.So anybody please help me in this situation.

EDIT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/index\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) apexengineeringproject.com [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^display_project.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /display_project.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC]
```

This is the content of my .htaccess file but problem is page gets loaded but not the styles and javascripts.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.apexengineeringproject.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^display_project.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /display_project.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC]             This is the content of my .htaccess file but problem is page gets loaded but not the styles and javascripts

Comment: Where are the styles/scripts located?

Comment: just try this 2 links you will come to know abt the error sir this link loads correctly [working link](http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php?id=AP112&title=ADVANCED%20OFFICE%20AUTOMATION%20SYSTEM%20USING%20GSM%20AND%20MICROCONTROLLER)  but this link [nonworking link](http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php/AP112/ADVANCED%20OFFICE%20AUTOMATION%20SYSTEM%20USING%20GSM%20AND%20MICROCONTROLLER) has some problem and about styles/scripts they are present in a folder called twitter-bootstrap-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you're referencing your script/style files using a relative file name. The browser will use the *whole directory path up to the last slash before the query string* for fetching relative paths.

For example, when using the page before rewrite;

```
http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php
```

...and it looks for a script at `scripts/test.js`, the browser will fetch it from;

```
http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/scripts/test.js
```

When using the page after rewrite;

```
http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php/AP112/ADVANCED%20OFFICE%20AUTOMATION%20SYSTEM%20USING%20GSM%20AND%20MICROCONTROLLER
```

...a fetch of the relative path `scripts/test.js` will fetch the file;

```
http://www.apexengineeringproject.com/display_project.php/AP112/scripts/test.js
```

...which presumably does not exist.

To fix the problem, just make your script paths and css paths relative to the server root, ie don't use `scripts/test.js`, instead use `/scripts/test.js`.

EDIT: Although I'd consider it slightly hacky, you could rewrite some files back to the root. Can't test this, but it should be close to what you want;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|css|png|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule display_project.php/[^/]*(.*) $1 [NC]
```

Comment: yes the above solution is working....but is there any other solution like redirecting all the request to the main domain link then rewriting the urls

Comment: @user2028204 Added a possible rewrite to rewrite the files back to the root.